# How to get words starting with # and remove from string

Tags: php, string

```
$query = "Hello #world What's #up"
$newquery = "Hello, What's"
```

So basically I wan't to remove the words starting with `#`.

Comment: have you tried looking at str_replace

Comment: Have you even tried something ?

Comment: What have you tried? Any ideas how to solve it? Here are a few things to think about: preg_replace() and a regular expression, writing a parser that tokenizes into words, loops over the tokens to delete those starting with `#` (which can be found with `$token{0}` easily) and then you concatenate them to a string again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "Hello #world What's #up";
$newquery = preg_replace('/#[^\s]+/', '', $query);
echo $newquery;
```

Comment: Dang, same answer at the same time.

Comment: But I was a little quicker ;)

Comment: Yeah, I decided to test my regex first to make sure it did what I expected. Shoulda just trusted my instinct

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```php
$newquery = preg_replace('/#[^\s]+/', '', $query);
```